# How can I change the browser logs that are displaying as per my requirement?

Tags: javascript, html

Previously, I used browser logs(console.log and debug.log) and I used to get the logs as shown below:

```
Dec 21 05:55:56 GALIO|NORMAL|package://ATFF-58C2A778/js/ATFF.js at line 49 FIPAPP::Setting config: ATF_ENABLED_TESTS_COUNT=4
Dec 21 05:55:56 GALIO|NORMAL|package://ATFF-58C2A778/js/ATFF.js at line 49 FIPAPP::Setting config: ATF_REST_API_URL=http://64.100.106.75:1503/restlet/dhct/sercureServices
Dec 21 05:55:56 GALIO|NORMAL|package://ATFF-58C2A778/js/ATFF.js at line 49 FIPAPP::Setting config: Test Config =undefined
Dec 21 05:55:56 GALIO|NORMAL|package://callid-9C03D013/js/callid.js at line 44 There was an unexpected error while connecting to the EventSource...
Dec 21 05:55:59 GALIO|NORMAL|package://callid-9C03D013/js/callid.js at line 44 There was an unexpected error while connecting to the EventSource...
Dec 21 05:56:02 GALIO|NORMAL|package://callid-9C03D013/js/callid.js at line 44 There was an unexpected error while connecting to the EventSource...
Dec 21 05:56:05 GALIO|NORMAL|package://callid-9C03D013/js/callid.js at line 44 There was an unexpected error while connecting to the EventSource...
Dec 21 05:56:08 GALIO|NORMAL|package://callid-9C03D013/js/callid.js at line 44 There was an unexpected error while connecting to the EventSource...
Dec 21 05:56:11 GALIO|NORMAL|package://callid-9C03D013/js/callid.js at line 44 There was an unexpected error while connecting to the EventSource...
Dec 21 05:56:12 GALIO|NORMAL|package://library-8EEB287C/js/channellistprocessor.js at line 579 RTNUI : ReplicaChannel : DEBUG : IdleTimer : EXPIRED : 560
Dec 21 05:56:12 GALIO|NORMAL|package://library-8EEB287C/js/channellistprocessor.js at line 579 RTNUI : ReplicaChannel : DEBUG : stopIdleTimer : 560
Dec 21 05:56:14 GALIO|NORMAL|package://callid-9C03D013/js/callid.js at line 44 There was an unexpected error while connecting to the EventSource...
```

In the above logs you can see "/js/callid.js", line number 44 and so on. It means that I have got the browser log in the file "callid.js" at line 44.

Now, I have overridden the browser logs with my "console.js" library so that, I get error, warn, info logs. Below is my library file:

```
(function () {
    /* dependencies */
    TVLib.Include.module('Utility');
    /* declare this module */
    TVLib.Core.declare('Console', false);

    var isMomDefined = typeof window.mom !== 'undefined';

    /**
     * Console constructor
     *
     * @param {String} prefix to add to any logging
     * @param {String=} prefix to namespace to add app name to logging (optional)
     * @return {TVLib.Console} console logging object
     */
    TVLib.Console = function (namespace, appName) {
        if (typeof namespace !== 'string') {
            throw new Error('TVLib.Console expects a string for the _namespace parameter');
        }
        this.appName = appName ? appName + ' ' : '';
        this.namespace = namespace;
        this.perfLogger = {};
        this.resetTimer = undefined;
    };
    TVLib.Console.prototype.namespace = '';

    function _log(namespace, level, args) {

        // Arguments don't behave like a normal array
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call(args);
        args.unshift('[' + this.appName + namespace + '] [' + level + '][' + Date.now() + ']');
        var force = false;
        // If last argument is boolean and true, force calling the debug.log function
        if (PVR.Utilities.isArray(args) && typeof args[args.length - 1] === 'boolean') {
            force = args.pop();
        }
        if (isMomDefined && window && window.console) {
            // Webkit on STB
            var str = args.join(' ');
            switch (level) {
            case 'DEBUG':
                window.console.debug.call(window.console, str);
                break;
            case 'INFO':
                window.console.info.call(window.console, str);
                break;
            case 'WARN':
                window.console.warn.call(window.console, str);
                break;
            case 'ERROR':
            case 'PERF':
                window.console.error.call(window.console, str);
                break;
            }
        } else {
            if (isMomDefined) {
                // MOM enabled browsers
                if (force) {
                    debug.log(args.join(' '));
                } else {
                    debug.log(args.join(' '));
                }
            } else {
                // Browsers with a regular console support
                switch (level) {
                case 'DEBUG':
                    window.console.debug.apply(window.console, args);
                    break;
                case 'INFO':
                    window.console.info.apply(window.console, args);
                    break;
                case 'WARN':
                    window.console.warn.apply(window.console, args);
                    break;
                case 'ERROR':
                case 'PERF':
                    window.console.error.apply(window.console, args);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    TVLib.Console.prototype.log = function () {
        _log.apply(this, [this.namespace, 'DEBUG', arguments]);
    };
    TVLib.Console.prototype.debug = function () {
        _log.apply(this, [this.namespace, 'DEBUG', arguments]);
    };
    TVLib.Console.prototype.info = function () {
        _log.apply(this, [this.namespace, 'INFO', arguments]);
    };
    TVLib.Console.prototype.warn = function () {
        _log.apply(this, [this.namespace, 'WARN', arguments]);
    };
    TVLib.Console.prototype.error = function () {
        _log.apply(this, [this.namespace, 'ERROR', arguments]);
    };
})();
```

After using this library, I get the logs as shown below:

```
Dec 21 06:32:12 GALIO|NORMAL|package://library-8EEB287C/js/console.js at line 52 [CallID] [DEBUG] There was an unexpected error while connecting to the EventSource...
Dec 21 06:32:14 GALIO|NORMAL|package://library-8EEB287C/js/console.js at line 52 [PVR PVR.PosterManager] [DEBUG] delayed bulk fetch timeout complete, starting bulk fetch...
Dec 21 06:32:14 GALIO|NORMAL|package://library-8EEB287C/js/console.js at line 52 [PVR PVR.PosterManager] [DEBUG] Preparing bulk fetch map...
Dec 21 06:32:14 GALIO|NORMAL|package://library-8EEB287C/js/console.js at line 52 [PVR PVR.PosterManager] [DEBUG] No posters to fetch.  No bulk fetch request will be performed.
Dec 21 06:32:15 GALIO|NORMAL|package://library-8EEB287C/js/console.js at line 52 [CallID] [DEBUG] There was an unexpected error while connecting to the EventSource...
Dec 21 06:32:18 GALIO|NORMAL|package://library-8EEB287C/js/console.js at line 52 [CallID] [DEBUG] There was an unexpected error while connecting to the EventSource...
Dec 21 06:32:21 GALIO|NORMAL|package://library-8EEB287C/js/console.js at line 52 [CallID] [DEBUG] There was an unexpected error while connecting to the EventSource...
Dec 21 06:32:24 GALIO|NORMAL|package://library-8EEB287C/js/console.js at line 52 [CallID] [DEBUG] There was an unexpected error while connecting to the EventSource...
```

In the above logs you can see that, all the logs(debug, warn, info) are getting fired from my console.js library and not from the callid.js file and also the line number is showing same for all the files.

Now what I want is that, I want to show the first logging system(with the correct file name and the line number) by using my "console.js" library.

Is there anything that I should change in my console.js library file?